# Keyword usage in java code

Tags: java, iterator, guava

Following is the code from com.google.common.collect.Iterators class in Google Guava library:

```
public static <T> Iterable<T> filter(Iterable<T> unfiltered, Predicate<? super T> predicate) {
            Preconditions.checkNotNull(unfiltered);
            Preconditions.checkNotNull(predicate);
            return new FluentIterable(unfiltered, predicate) {
                public Iterator<T> iterator() {
                    return Iterators.filter(this.val$unfiltered.iterator(), this.val$predicate);
                }
            };
        }
```

I could not find any declaration of val in the class. What does this.val$unfiltered refers to in the above code.

Comment: Which version of Guava are you using? **[The code here](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/src-html/com/google/common/collect/Iterators.html#line.608)** seems different from yours.

Comment: Was this decompiled somewhere? Specifically, the `this.val` looks like synthetic code.

Comment: Yes, decompiled in eclipse using jd.  The version is guava 19.0

Comment: No need for decompilation. The source code is available at Github. https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/guava/src/com/google/common/collect/Iterators.java#L608

Comment: Just don't decompile: it's not worth the effort. Guava is a free (as in speech) library. You can browse the entire [source code online](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/guava/src/com/google/common/collect/Iterators.java#L604) (with comments!). Regarding your question itself, the `this.val` comes from the fact that JD has issues decompiling anonymous inner classes. `this.val` refers to an undefined object that contains the variables given from the caller to the anonymous inner classes.

Comment: `val` is not a Java keyword, by the way. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/_keywords.html

Comment: Thanks for your comments. The code from github makes more sense.